# filter array of objects based on separate object keys, values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, javascript-objects

I have the array of people below:

```
  const FIRST_ARRAY = [
    {
      name: 'Simon',
      age: 32,
      occupation: 'Student'
    },
    {
      name: 'Vera',
      age: 22,
      occupation: 'Developer'
    }
  ];
```

I would like to filter the array to produce a separate array based on a 'filters' object.

For example if my filters are:

```
  const FILTERS = {
    age: 32,
    name: 'John',
    occupation: ''
  };
```

The new array should be empty as no people in the array have the combination of 32 and John. However if my filters are:

```
 const FILTERS = {
    age: 32,
    name: 'Simon',
    occupation: ''
  }
```

The new array of people returned will be:

```
 const NEW_ARRAY = [
    {
      name: 'Simon',
      age: 32,
      occupation: 'Student'
    }
  ];
```

How can I filter the array of people by iterating over the 'filters' object values? Bare in mind the filters keys and values will dynamically changing all the time.

Comment: You have not actually asked any questions.

Comment: `occupation: ''` is misleading as a filter value. Omitting a property would be a bit more logical.

Comment: Is `occupation` necessary as a filter?

Comment: isn't it normal search/filter? like Filter_Array.where(f=>(f.age== age || isnullorEmpty(age)) && (f.name == name || isnullorEmpty(name)) && (c.occupation == occupation || isnullorEmpty(occupation))); Modify in javascript but logic should be similar

Comment: The occupation can be omitted if the string is empty. However it will exist in the filters object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could filter as follows:

```js
const FIRST_ARRAY = [
  {
    name: 'Simon',
    age: 32,
    occupation: 'Student'
  },
  {
    name: 'Vera',
    age: 22,
    occupation: 'Developer'
  }
];

const FILTERS = {
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 32,
  occupation: ''
};

const filtered = FIRST_ARRAY.filter(person => Object.entries(FILTERS)
  .every(([key, val]) => val !== '' ? person[key] === val : true));
  
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `filter` and the function `every` to check that every key-value are equal to the `FILTERS` values.

*Assuming when within the FILTERS a value is empty then skip it*

```js
const FIRST_ARRAY = [{name: 'Simon',age: 32,occupation: 'Student'},{name: 'Vera',age: 22,occupation: 'Developer'}],
      FILTERS = {age: 32,name: 'Simon',occupation: ''},
      keys = Object.keys(FILTERS),
      result = FIRST_ARRAY.filter(o => keys.every(k =>  FILTERS[k] === '' || FILTERS[k] === o[k]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
const FILTERS = { age: 32, name: 'John', occupation: '' };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```js
    function compare(item, filter) {
      for (var property in filter) {
        if (filter.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          let value = filter[property];
          return item.hasOwnProperty(property) && item[property] != '' && value == item[property];
        }
      }
    }
    
    const DATA = [
        {
          name: 'Simon',
          age: 32,
          occupation: 'Student'
        },
        {
          name: 'Vera',
          age: 22,
          occupation: 'Developer'
        }
      ];
      
    const filter = {
        age: 32,
        name: 'Simon',
        occupation: ''
      };
      
    let result = DATA.filter(function(item) {
        return compare(item, filter);
      })
      
      console.log(result);
```